# Is touching your penis allowed? (No rubbing or masturbation) (please answer fast)

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation, touching

I know that masturbation is not allowed and rubbing it in bath is not allowed too, but is touching your penis haram if you do not do anything else with it?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be permissible?

Comment: Why are you doing it? Touching it with desire is a form of masturbation. Touching it to clean it or to scratch an itch or to shave pubic hair etc. is obviously permitted.

Comment: It's a body part of yours. You can do whatever u please with it. But if u're talking from the point of desires and masturbation. Then that's another fiqh issue and another discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Assalamu alaikum,

Touching your private parts is allowed, but not with the right hand. However, your fast will still count but your wudu wouldnt and so it is an act of inpurity.
Hope this helped!
Salam

Comment: Please add evidences to support your claims and read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

If you touch it without a barrier between the Hand and IT  ( eg : Clothes ) then your Wudhu will break. You have to do Wudhu even if you are not going to pray afterwards.

However your fast won't break.

Burkra bin Safwan narrated that the Prophet ( PBUH ) said :

" Whoever touches *IT* cannot pray until he performs ablution  (Wudhu) "

Allah knows best

Comment: You should mark quotes as such and add the relevant sources. A hadith you quote must have a source and reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can only touch it with your left hands but not before you pray. if u do before you pray u cant pray until you do wudu. but after or way before praying you may only touch it with your left hand. hope this helps, salam

Answer (score 0):

The are basic principles when it comes to discussing halal and haram in Islam and one of them is, as Sh Qarawdawi says in his famous book  on the lawful and prophbitied in Islam, the following:

"Nothing is haram except what is prohibited by a sound and explicit nas (Nas denotes either a verse of the Qur‘ân or a clear, authentic, and explicit sunnah (practice or saying) of Prophet Muhammad. These are the two main sources of Islâmic law, i.e., its Shari‘ah. (Trans.)) from the Law-Giver, Allâh Subhanahu wa Ta‘ala. If the nas is not sound, as for example in the case of a weak hadith, or if it is not explicit in stating the prohibition, the original principle of permissibility applies."

You have to show with proofs that the action you mentioned is haram with clear evidence, otherwise you assume that it is halal. In other words, things are halal unless proven otherwise.

As for masturbation, there is NOT a scholarly consensus on this matter and I wish people would stop making proclamations of haram as if that was the final word on the subject because this is not demonstrating scholarly integrity. In a 17 minute presentation on this topic, Sh Yasir Qadhi addressed the various opinions on masturbation before offering his own, and many of you will be surprised. In youtube search "The Islamic Ruling on Masturbation | Ask Shaykh YQ #95"

Answer (score -1):

It should be noted that the scholars of Islam differ among themselves concerning touching the penis or vulva, and whether that invalidates wudu or not.

Comment: I don't think the OP is concerned about whether touching the private parts would break wudu, cuz it's not mentioned in the question.